# SVG scaling from center point

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this piece of code, and I wanted the SVG objects to expand upon hover. I looked up a solution to make the SVG object expand from the center of the shape, but it's unresponsive. My other attempt was to simply transform it using `a:hover` and using CSS transformations, but as you might expect, it scales, but also moves away from the canvas.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 850px;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}

a:hover {
  background: gray;
  /*Attempt to scale using CSS, but there was a failure
  transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1.5);*/
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

div#navPanel {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="c1">
        <path
        d="
        M 10, 0
        L 200, 80
        L 300, 60
        Z
        "/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#c1" transform="translate(-50,-50) scale (1.5)"/>
  </svg>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navPanel">
    <a href="#1" class="clipPath1" style="clip-path: url(#c1)">Click me...</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that `<clipPath>` elements don't render anything, so your `<use>` element is pointless here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made it hard for yourself by using clip paths. Your problem is that the clip Paths have absolute coordinates.  When you scale the `<a>` element up, you can't tell anything has happened because the clip path has stayed the same size.

You need to scale the clip path up.  Which you can only do with Javascript.  See below.

```js
var item = document.getElementById("item1");

item.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
  document.querySelector("#c1 path").setAttribute("transform",
    "translate(155,40) scale(1.5) translate(-155,-40)");
});

item.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
  document.querySelector("#c1 path").removeAttribute("transform");
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 850px;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}

a:hover {
  background: gray;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

div#navPanel {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <svg>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="c1">
        <path
        d="
        M 10, 0
        L 200, 80
        L 300, 60
        Z
        " />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navPanel">
    <a id="item1" href="#1" class="clipPath1" style="clip-path: url(#c1)">Click me...</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

The enlarged clip path is itself being clipped by the edge of the `<a>` element. You could fix that by moving the clip path away from the edge. Ie increase the coordinate values in the clip path.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in width and height of the `<a>` tag

Here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/2/

**CSS**

```
a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

a:hover {
  background: gray;
  /* Attempt to scale using CSS, but there was a failure */
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}

svg {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

div#navPanel {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10vw;
}
```

Comment: The problem is: I have many different objects drawn within the navigation panel, the panel takes up roughly 1500px by 850px of space. This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/3/

Comment: Okay, lemme try to fix this, thanks for the updated fiddle.. :)

Comment: Make work around for it : [https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/5/)

Comment: If you can give css to each a tag, then you can adjust the scaling effect. I applied css for upper and lower sections : [https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/0we13sx9/6/)